# close parent dialog after child dialog open

Tags: android

### In my application I am using one "Alert Dialog" which has three Buttons as follows .

after clicking each button one child dialog would open. now I want to close parent dialog  automatically after clicking on any button. 
     here is my code:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alertForSelectOperation=new AlertDialog.Builder(DisplayTable_Grid.this); 
            final LinearLayout linear=new LinearLayout(DisplayTable_Grid.this);
            linear.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

            Button update=(Button)new Button(DisplayTable_Grid.this);
            //update.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(3,12,90));
            update.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font size=10>Update</font>"));
            update.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {   @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) 
    {   
                final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogOK_CANCEL=new AlertDialog.Builder(DisplayTable_Grid.this); 
                final LinearLayout linearlayout=new LinearLayout(DisplayTable_Grid.this);
                linearlayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                alertDialogOK_CANCEL.setView(linearlayout);
            alertDialogOK_CANCEL.setTitle("insert values here");
            alertDialogOK_CANCEL.create();
            alertDialogOK_CANCEL.show();
            }
    }

Button delete=(Button)new Button(DisplayTable_Grid.this);
delete.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font size=10> Delete</font>"));
delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {   
                @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) 
    {
                final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogOK_CANCEL=new AlertDialog.Builder(DisplayTable_Grid.this); 
                alertDialogOK_CANCEL.setMessage("Press OK to Delete this Record");
                alertDialogOK_CANCEL.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {   @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1)
        }
        });

                alertDialogOK_CANCEL.setNegativeButton("CANCEL",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {   @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1)
                {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                }
        });
                alertDialogOK_CANCEL.create();
                alertDialogOK_CANCEL.show();
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `alertForSelectOperation.dismiss();` this line in your button click listener to dismiss your parent Alert Dialog, before `alertDialogOK_CANCEL.show(); and alertDialogOK_CANCEL.show();`

Comment: its not working.when i put this line it gives error.

Comment: is there any other way to do this

Comment: error is dismiss method is not applicable .this object doesnt accepts that methos.now what should i do

Comment: Can u please update your question with your Complete Parent Dialog code with 3 buttons.